# iPhone : Problem while fetching the twits from twitter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In my iphone app, I am trying to fetch twits from twitter.

And I got one example coding from following link :

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-json-twitter-api/

But when i implemented this example I got following warning:

Directory not found for option '-L/Volumes/MacShare/Ankit/Twitter Search/JSON/iphoneos.sdk/usr/local/lib'

What can be done?

Comment: if you are trying with this then why did you deaccept my previous answer... why you accept "Adrian Sarli" answer??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are forgetting the step of copying the JSON framework in your project -

```
# Drag the JSON folder from the DMG and drop it in your Xcode project. You can add it to the “Other Sources” group if you would like.
# Select the ‘Copy items into destination group’s folder’ option when prompted.
```

I just downloaded the code from http://mobiletuts.s3.amazonaws.com/14_iPhoneJSONFramework/JSONTwitterSearch.zip and its working great!!

follow the steps carefully!!

You can do one more thing.. download their source code and drag the Json folder from their project to your project..